# Get the returned variable out of a function and into a document.write

Tags: javascript

Pretty new to this,

Just trying to get the form input into the generator and out the bottom display. The generator and display are connected just need to get the form input to feed into the generator now

Any help would be appreciated!

```
      </head>
      <body>
      <div class="background-color">
      <h1>Welcome to the Fibonacci Generator!</h1>

      <h2>Please input a number between 1 and 10</h2>

      <div class="container">
      <form class="pure-form">
       <input class="numberInputBox" autocomplete="off" id="name"
      type="number" placeholder="            Enter # Here!" />
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success heighttext">GO! 
      </button>
      </form>

      <script type="text/javascript">

      var nameInput = document.getElementById('name');

      document.querySelector('form.pure- 
       form').addEventListener('submit',
      function (e) {

       e.preventDefault();
      });

      </script>
      </div>
      <div class="display">
      <script type="text/javascript">
      </script>
      <h1>
      <script type="text/javascript">
      function fibonacciGenerator(n) {
        var seq = [0, 1];
        for (var i = 2; i < n; i++) {
          seq.push(seq.at(-1) + seq.at(-2));
        }
        seq.length = n;
        return seq;
      }

      document.write(fibonacciGenerator(10));
      </script>
      </h1>
       </div>
       </div>
       </div>
       </div>
       </div>
       </body>
       </html>
       <footer>
       <div class="footer">
       </div>
       </footer>
```

Comment: `result` is not an HTML element.  It's just a Javascript variable.  You can't fetch it that way.  Just say `var number=result;`, or use `result` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a very simple example of passing the result of a `fibonacciGenerator` function to `document.write`.

```js
function fibonacciGenerator(n) {
  var seq = [0, 1];
  for (var i = 2; i < n; i++) {
    seq.push(seq.at(-1) + seq.at(-2));
  }
  seq.length = n;
  return seq;
}

document.write(fibonacciGenerator(10));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! So close to getting the submitted input to go through the generator and out the bottom display!

Answer (score 0):

If you trying to get "result" by using document.getElementById, that doesn't work. getElementById return a tag from the DOM.

You the to attached the var "result" to some tag in you DOM.